# Javascript add comma to price without deleting DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, wordpress

I am using the WP-Properties plugin on a client's WordPress site. The prices need a comma for thousands. The HTML on the page is:

```
<li class="property_price">
<div>Price:   </div> $54000.00 USD
</li>
```

You can not add commas to the price in the plugin admin because commas designate rows in the dropdown menus. So I am using the following javascript to add the commas:

```
function addCommas(nStr)
{
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
$(".property_price").each(function() {
   var self = $(this), text = self.text();
   self.text(addCommas(text));
});
```

This works, but it also stripes out the `<div>` around the label so the resulting HTML is:

```
<li class="property_price">
Price:    $54,000.00 USD
</li>
```

How do I tweak the javascript so it adds the comma and keeps the `<div>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use

```
$(".property_price").each(function() {
   var self = $(this), text = self.text();
   self.html("<div>" + addCommas(text) + "</div>");
});
```

Just simply append the `<div></div>` tags to the HTML that's being inserted. Also, you should be using `.html()` instead of `.text()` when playing with HTML

Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/VTjeM/ for a sample.

**EDIT**

As James Montagne pointed out, this doesn't work. However I revised the example, and [this one works](http://jsfiddle.net/VTjeM/1/).

It takes a different approach (it gets the HTML, deletes the `div`, calculates the value with the comma, then rebuilds the HTML).

**EDIT**

Here is the full code that worked for me.  I'm marking this as my accepted answer ~Trishah:

```
    function addCommas(nStr) {
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
$(".property_price").each(function () {
    var self = $(this);
    // remove the div, we don't need it
    self.find("div").remove();
    text = self.text();
    self.html("<div>Price: </div>" + addCommas(text));
});
```

Comment: This changes the structure of the html.  In the original, only the label is wrapped in the `div` and not the value.  After your code, both are in the div.

Comment: What I like about this answer is I can use it for other fields that also need the comma, like property size in sq.ft.  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the individual text node rather than the `<div>` element. Most jQuery methods exclude text nodes from it's result (`find()`, `children()` etc.), but [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents) preserves them.

```
$(".property_price").each(function() {
   var target = $(this).contents().last(), text = target.text();
   target.replaceWith(addCommas(text));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n6GbC/1/

Comment: At least in FF, this doesn't work.  Your fiddle does not change the text at all.

Comment: Since you community wiki'd it, I went ahead and updated it to `replaceWith`, which works.

Comment: @JamesMontagne: Thanks for the fix, but weird that it didn't work. Currently trying to find out why...

Comment: Ok, jQuery does a lot more in `text()` than simply setting the `textContent` or `innerText` of the element in question; it tries to append another text node to the text node, which browsers don't seem to like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.html()` as opposed to the `.text()`.  This will let you split on the div and rebuild the html after adding the commas:

```
$(".property_price").each(function() {
   var self = $(this), text = self.html();
   var texts = text.split('</div>');
   self.html(texts[0] + '</div>' + addCommas(texts[1]));
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ihkGn

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a Regular expression to include what's in the div, something like:

```
(\<div\>\w+\:?\s+?\</div\> )|\$?(\d+).(\d{1,3})
```

This would let you get both values, regardless of what's in it.

Answer (score 0):

Why has no one suggested modifying the wordpress plugin? Why would you introduce a bunch of javascript to your page when you could simply do something like this where the plugin outputs the html for the price:

```
<?php echo money_format($price); ?>
```

OP, If you post more info about the plugin I could help you out.