# clone element and append after original

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am needing to clone an element and put the clone in the exact same or after spot.

I am cloning like so:

```
var holderColumn = $('.holder').parent('.column');
$('.holder').clone().appendTo(holderColumn).removeClass('holder').addClass('olderHolder').css('background', 'red');
```

So I am appending the clone to the original's parent. How can I append it to the original's parent, but right after the original?

Comment: @ MrGuru: It's *well worth* your time to stop what you're doing and take two hours to read [the jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com) from beginning to end. It really only takes that long, and you'll discover all kinds of useful, time-saving things. You'll get that two hours back within a week, maybe less.

Comment: @MrGuru: You're cloning `.holder`, then removing the `.holder` from the *clone* and adding `.olderHolder` to it. But...it's a *newer* holder, not an older one. Just mentioning it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder true, newerHoler should be the class name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/).

```
var holder = $('.holder');
holder.clone().insertAfter(holder).removeClass('holder').addClass('olderHolder').css('background', 'red');
```

See also the similar method [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/). Note that `insertAfter()` returns the newly appended element.

Comment: Re your CW ethos: Your answers are *already* open to editing by other people (who have [contributed usefully](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) to a degree in the past). That's half of what makes SO so useful. But by making your answers CW, you rob people evaluating answers of the useful information provided by your rep. Rep is a useful indicator of gravitas. :-) Also, there's a *reason* editing other people's answers is limited to >2,000 rep users. The threshold for editing a CW, on the other hand, is 100. Not nearly enough to keep vandalism at bay.

Comment: It is inserting in the container grandparent of `.holder`. How can I get it to be after `.holder` and in .holder's parent?

Comment: @MrGuru: That's what `insertAfter` *does*. You must be looking at something else, or moving it later.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Then how can I move it after the original element, but inside the holderColumn selector?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Whilst the system allows it, people generally *don't*. With CW however, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23397608/javascript-add-comma-to-price-without-deleting-div/23397649#comment35848254_23397649). I've got all the unicorn dollars I need now, so I'm not too fussed on that front :). In this particular post however, it was such a lame answer, I'd feel bad collecting the rep for it anyway :P.

Comment: @MrGuru: Have you got multiple `.holder` elements or something? Does using `var holder = $('.column > .holder');` instead work?

Comment: @MrGuru: Again: That's what `insertAfter` does. [Example](http://jsbin.com/tuvutode/1/edit) If you're having trouble implementing it, you'll need to create a [minimal replicating example](http://sscce.org).

Comment: No. Only one `.holder` at a time. And the moment I clone it, I remove the `.holder` class. When I insert after `holder`, it inserts in the parent of the parent of holder, when I want it to insert in the parent of holder.

Comment: @Matt: Yeah, I've done that for this kind of answer too. :-) But seriously, beware the vandalism thing. Your call, but I'd stick to using the site the way it's intended to be used.

Comment: @MrGuru: What I've posted works; http://jsbin.com/tuvutode/2/edit. You'll have to edit your post to include a [MRE like T.J. Crowder said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24041824/clone-element-and-append-after-original/24041912#comment37065402_24041912).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Aye, point taken. To be fair, I've never experienced any vandalism of my posts thus far... you can never speak too soon though :P.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the jquery [insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) function rather than appendTo.

```
$('.holder').clone().insertAfter('.holder').removeClass('holder').addClass('olderHolder').css('background', 'red');
```